# All test failing after update from laravel 7 to laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-testing, laravel-8

After update from laravel 7 to version 8 all test failing with same error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such index: IDX_426EF39216FE72E1 (SQL: DROP INDEX IDX_426EF39216FE72E1)
```

I am also using `legacy-factories` package for old factories approach

Comment: please share more info about test fails and work you have been done

Comment: I follow upgrade guide as I always did. everything works fine except testing because all test are failing with error that I share

Comment: There is clearly an index there isn't there, on the table it fails, can you post all index created there or similar

Comment: It fails on all test and I don't see any connection between fails and index. When I switch to laravel 7 with same tables everything works perfect

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve this problem using laravel shift because there is lot of things to be done after upgrade and list in my case is huge because I use custom namespace and I must handle that in `AppServiceProvider`. Shift also refactor all of mine factories that I have