# Laravel passport test fails after update to laravel 8

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-passport

After update to laravel 8 my passport tests fail because of factory and for all test I get message like this:

```
BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Laravel\Passport\Client::factory()
```

Comment: your previous question said all tests failed, now it is only passport tests? and this was a test that worked before the upgrade?

Comment: yes, I adapt all factories that I have, modify some things. Now I have a problem with Client::factory() of Passport

Comment: also perhaps you would like to resolve your last question you posted

Comment: the `Laravel\Passport\Client` model does not implement the `HasFactory` trait so it won't have a `factory` method

Comment: But in passport documentation (section testing) there is same factory call like any regular laravel model

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/10.x/src/Client.php ... it does not use that trait and it does not have a `factory` method

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#testing

Comment: you can keep referencing that all you want, it does not change the fact that this does not have that method ... it would appear the docs are wrong

Answer (score 1):

The `Laravel\Passport\Client` model does not use the `HasFactory` trait. You will have to call the factory directly:

```
Laravel\Passport\Database\Factories\ClientFactory::new()->count(3)->make();
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Database Testing - Model Factories - Creating Models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#creating-models)

Comment: I create factory directly but now for this code
```
$building = Building::factory()->create();
        Passport::actingAsClient(
            PassportClientFactory::new()->create(),
        );

        $response = $this->get('/api/buildings/'.$building->id);

        $response->assertStatus(200);
        $response->assertJsonFragment(['name' => $building->name]);
```
I got this:
```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target class [bindings] does not exist.

```

Comment: i dont understand what that means "but now for this code"?

Comment: also you still have not resolved your last question you posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63870060/all-test-failing-after-update-from-laravel-7-to-laravel-8

Comment: use the stacktrace to help find where that error is coming from, would be hard to tell just based on that ... just put a single backtick at the beginning of the code and one at the end to format it in the comments `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve this issue by removing namespace for api routes in RoutesServiceProvider. I also use `\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class` instead of bindings in api middleware groups (Kernel.php) and I use controller class in api routes